# Android Проблема добавления собственного view в Horizontal LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Создаю View. LinearLayout с точками в нем, расположенными горизонтально (навигационные точки для ViewFlipper). Выбранный итем подкрашивается оранжевым, не выранный белым. Для начала создаю точку. У точки есть основной цвет и черная обводка.

```
public class NewCircleView extends View {

    Paint mainPaint;
    Paint outerPaint;

    int cx;
    int cy;
    int r;

    public NewCircleView(Context context, int diameter) {
        super(context);
        setMinimumWidth(diameter);
        setMinimumHeight(diameter);
        r = cy = cx = diameter / 2;
        setMainParams();
    }

    public NewCircleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        int[] attrsArray = new int[] {
                android.R.attr.layout_width,
                android.R.attr.layout_height
        };
        TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, attrsArray);
        cx = ta.getDimensionPixelSize(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        cy = ta.getDimensionPixelSize(1, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        cx = cx /2;
        cy = cy /2;
        r = cx > cy ? cy : cx;
        ta.recycle();

        setMainParams();
    }

    public void switchColorToWhite() {
        mainPaint.setColor(Decorator.WHITE);
        invalidate();
    }
    public void switchColorToOrange() {
        mainPaint.setColor(Decorator.ORANGE);
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        mainPaint.setColor(color);
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy,r,outerPaint);
        canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy,r-2,mainPaint);
    }

    private void setMainParams() {
        mainPaint = new Paint();
        mainPaint.setColor(Decorator.WHITE);
        outerPaint = new Paint();
        outerPaint.setColor(Decorator.BLACK);
    }
}
```

Дальше нам нужен слой, куда мы будем помещать эти точки. Делать это надо динамически, так как слайдов для ViewFlipper может быть разное количество.

```
public class DotBar extends LinearLayout {

    ArrayList<NewCircleView> dots = new ArrayList<>();

    public DotBar(Context context, int dotsCount) {
        super(context);
        setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);
        setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Decorator.LLWC, Decorator.LLWC));
        for (int i = 0; i < dotsCount; i++) {
            dots.add(new NewCircleView(context, Decorator.dipToPx(8)));
        }
        for (NewCircleView dot : dots) {
            addView(dot);
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    public void setPosition(int position) {
        for (int i = 0; i < dots.size(); i++) {
            if (i == position) dots.get(position).switchColorToOrange();
            else dots.get(i).switchColorToWhite();
        }
    }

}
```

Суть вопроса такая. Когда я добавляю CircleView на DotView, несмотря на то, что Orientation у меня задан, всё равно получается наслоение точек друг на друга. В моем случае я передаю в dotsCount 5, и добавляю DotBar на слой с ViewFlipper, но на слое с ViewFlipper я вижу не 5 точек, а только одну.

Собственно код, который добавляет дотБар

```
        mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);

        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) mainView.findViewById(R.id.parent);
        dotBar = new DotBar(getActivity(), Data.slides.size());
        layout.addView(dotBar);
```

C cозданием собственных View  я не очень опытен, мог допустить какую нибудь базовую ошибку. Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему.

Comment: а может вам сделать точку через ресурсы? например через шэйпы или вообще две png картинки

Comment: Засорять код мне приятнее, чем засорять ресурсы, чисто субъективно :) Точка прекрасно отрисовывается и так, с этим проблем нет. Проблемы в том, что несколько View некорректно добавляются в LinearLayout

Comment: а попробуйте вместо этой вью добавить обычные, чтобы немного ограничить области поиска

Comment: С текствью проблем нет, добавляется, как и ожидалось, в линию.

Comment: ЧТо то мне подсказывает, что у моего view размер 0, и поэтому оно добавляется в одно место

Comment: Так и есть, надо было явно задать LayoutParams